# How can I disable user to choose "show hidden file"?

Tags: windows, hide

How can I disable users to choose "show hidden files" in setting?
I want to use a .bat file to protect my files.( I've already got the batch - I use it to HIDE and UNHIDE )
But the problem is, the user can simply show hidden files.

Can I disable this option?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you can't.  It's the user's computer, not yours, and he or she is entitled to see those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open regedit and change the CheckedValue from 1 to 0 at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/Current Version/Explorer/Advanced/Folder/Hidden/SHOWALL
```

and restart.

Do remember to backup the registry first.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I already knew. It is useful, and brilliant. Will this, I can make a batch program to hide files and unhide. Simple protection!

Comment: It is improper for a program to make a change to the user's settings without the user's permission.  Besides, this doesn't prevent the user from changing the setting back again.

Answer (score -1):

Just write a bit of code to check this setting every 3 seconds or so and if it has changed, set it back again. Oh, and it is fine to change settings on a "Company Owned computer" or even a BYOD Computer without the users knowledge! Most users have no business playing with hidden files anyway...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).